# The "Edit" screen seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

I saw an open edit on a question, and when I clicked it I got this:

[image: broken edit screen]

One of the buttons is shown only partly, and I think there are some buttons missing.

Browser is Chrome 47.0.2526.111 on Windows 7 (x64). Zoom is 100%.

Comment: Have you tried zooming out on your browser?

Comment: Have you tried updating your chrome? 48.0.2564.82 is available.

Comment: Is your window full, or is another window also occupying part of the screen? And, is this same problem occurring with other windows/applications (where part of it is being cut off)?

Comment: @SirPython Window is full. Haven't seen any issues elsewhere.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: This should be fixed with upcoming build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Review uses very original layout comparing to other SE network sites. We had to use quite a lot of CSS hacks to make it looking good. Some of those hacks apparently affected popup module and its sizing.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I've fixed that and it should be good now.

Comment: I'll trust that it's fixed. Quite frankly I don't often see such edits here, so I can't check.